# AutoLayout and Size class for ipad UI Design using Storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, uistoryboard, size-classes

How to design Separate view Design for landscape and portrait in storyboard for ipad? I have learned to use Storyboard with Auto layout class. There is an option to add separate view for iPhone using wCompact and hRegular. But there is no option for ipad. Can any one suggest way to design seperate ipad landscape and ipad portrait using size class.

Comment: i think you know that regular means large amount of screen space and compact means small amount of screen space

Comment: I just answered this question where you asked about [size class constraints for the iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650332/uitraitcollection-class-for-updating-the-size-class).

Answer (score 0):

Read the text under Final Value

[image]
[image]

Comment: iPad registers as wRegular hRegular whether it is in landscape or portrait orientation, so it's not as simple as designing two different layouts using the size classes you provided.