# UITraitCollection Class for Updating the Size Class

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, size-classes, uitraitcollection

Shall i use UITraitCollection Class for Updating the Size Class constraints? Is this Best Practice to update the Constraints?

I have gone through the UITraitCollection, but don't know how to differentiate portrait and Landscape?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a different layout based on iPad orientation.
If adjusting constraint values is all you need to do, you can check the `UITraitCollection`'s `horizontalSizeClass` and `verticalSizeClass` properties.  The size class properties values can be found at the Apple documentation for [`UIUserInterfaceSizeClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIUserInterfaceSizeClass).  I can't vouch for this being best practice, but I don't see anything wrong with it.  An alternative to checking the `UITraitCollection` would be to check `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait` as seen below in the code snippet.

A more complex scenario requires the use of completely different constraints for landscape vs portrait.  You could handle adding those constraints programmatically, or you can use a different size class to add the constraints and then create an `IBOutletCollection` for the constraints for each size class that are based on the orientation.

For example, I used wAnyhRegular to setup my portrait iPad layout and then used wRegularhAny to setup my landscape iPad layout.  (Although you may want to use wRegular/hRegular as one of your orientation layouts since iPad registers as wRegular/hRegular when you check the `UITraitCollection`.  Hopefully the code below demonstrates how I went about it:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSLayoutConstraint) NSArray *iPadPortraitConstraints;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSLayoutConstraint) NSArray *iPadLandscapeConstraints;
```

My portrait constraints can be seen below.  My landscape has 3 constraints as well.
[image: Portrait Constraints]

I then apply the constraints as noted below (not shown, viewDidLoad executes `_needsiPadConstraintsApplied = YES;`):

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self applyiPadConstraints];
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    //  Size Classes does not support differentiating between iPad Portrait & Landscape.
    //  Signal that the iPad rotated so we can manually change the constraints.
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        _needsiPadConstraintsApplied = YES;
    }
}
- (void)applyiPadConstraints {

    if (_needsiPadConstraintsApplied) {

        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
            [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.iPadLandscapeConstraints];
            [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:self.iPadPortraitConstraints];

        } else {
            [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.iPadPortraitConstraints];
            [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:self.iPadLandscapeConstraints];
        }

        _needsiPadConstraintsApplied = NO;
    }
}
```

And finally, you may find this [exploration of size classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633172/sizing-class-for-ipad-portrait-and-landscape-modes/28268200#28268200) helpful.

Comment: You shouldn't use statusBarOrientation. You should use the UITraitCollection as a variable to check against.